# Starting Android Emulator in peppermint OS Hangs or error

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

From Android studio (Version 3.4), if we create emulator with or without Google Play Store option specially from peppermint OS, then System is hanged or mostly it is throw error while creating AVD. Also I did Virtualisation settings ON from BIOS setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some trick to create and open AVD in such case.

1. Update Emulator from SDK Manager.

   i. Go to SDK manager

   ii. Select SDK Tools tab

   iii. Select "Android Emulator" and Click on Apply. (Wait till download complete)
2. Create Emulator WITHOUT Play Store.
3. Advance Settings change Emulated Performance(Graphics) to "Software -GLES".
4. Click on Next and it will create your emulator and now you can start your emulator.